# How to submit a bootstrap form with 'required' elements with onClick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

The reasons are:

1. The submit button is outside the `</form>`
2. I need to use bootstrap as a form validation with `required` fields

But, when I submit the form with `onClick`. It's just submit the form without checking - even it's blank.

```js
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
         $('#billing-form').submit();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="clearfix" id="billing-form" method="post">
    
      <!-- NAME -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" required/>
      </div>
       .
       .
       .    
    </form>

    //coupon
    <input type="text" name="coupon" />
    <button type="button" id="submit">Buy now!</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've got it.

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    if($("#billing-form")[0].checkValidity()) {
      //do ajax submit
    }
    else {
        $("#billing-form")[0].reportValidity();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `checkValidity` method. It will return true/false depending on whether the form is valid or not

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
  var x = document.getElementById('billing-form').checkValidity();
  if (x) {
    $('#billing-form').submit();
  } else {
    console.log('Not Valid')
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="clearfix" id="billing-form" method="post">

  <!-- NAME -->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" required/>
  </div>

</form>

<input type="text" name="coupon" />
<button type="button" id="submit">Buy now!</button>
```

Comment: Can I have something just like this. Easy `required` attribute with built-in popup. http://jsfiddle.net/x7pooh99/182/